# incrementing by 1 for a row and column for a slice

Tags: python, numpy, increment

I have tried to write the program below:

```
    import numpy as np    #import package for scientific computing 
    dna1 = str(np.load('dna1.npy'))    
    def count(dna1, repeat):
    i = 0
    for s in range(len(dna1)):
        if (s =='repeat'):
            i += 1
            s += dna1[0:1]
        return i
    repeat = 'TTTT'
    n = count(dna1, repeat)
    print ('{repeat} occurs {n} times in dna1'.format(repeat=repeat, n=n))
```

I want to extract every possible combination of 4 letters in a list and check whether they are equal to `'TTTT'`. But I do not know how to increment to make s shift by 1 position in my list but still read 4 letters.

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of your dataset? Difficult to know exactly how to do your looping without knowing its structure.

Comment: Sure! dna1 = 'TAGCAGAAGTTGTCTCATGGACTGTATAACTCTTGCTACGCTTATTACTTTCAAACCTCCTTTGGAATGTATTTGGGCTCTAAAAATCGCCCTGAGTGACTCCAGTATATCAATTTACTCTGTTTGTCATATCTGCAGACTTGCAATACTATTCAAGCTGATAATAGAAAGTAGGGGCTATAACGACTTTTCTCACCACTGACATTGTACCCTAGTATTCAATACTAATAGGTCCGCTATATTAGATCTAAAATGCATATT....' It goes on and on

Comment: First of all there must be some match function in python, google "regex match function python", secondly, in psudo code I would do: loop the whole string, and for each letter in str[i] match a substring i..i+3 with "TTTT".

Comment: so to make it clearer i want to loop and test dna1[0:4] then dna1[1:5], dna1[2:6] etcera etcera... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that trying to use a regex is probably the easiest initial approach:

```
import numpy as np    #import package for scientific computing 
import re

dna1 = str(np.load('dna1.npy'))    

def count(dna1, repeat):
    regex = re.compile(repeat)
    result = regex.findall(dna1)
    return len(result)

repeat = 'TTTT'
n = count(dna1, repeat)
print ('{repeat} occurs {n} times in dna1'.format(repeat=repeat, n=n))
```

EDIT:

Here's a simple approach that doesn't use the regex module -- and you could certainly do some optimizations to skip ahead based each iteration's results:

```
def count(dna1, repeat):
    repeat_length = len(repeat)
    total = 0
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(dna1):
      substr = dna1[idx:idx+repeat_length]
      if substr == repeat:
        total += 1
        idx += repeat_length # skip ahead to avoid repeat counting
      else:
        idx += 1
    return total
```

Comment: Thank you! It does work this way, but is there a way to increment a slice then? or is it too complicated?

Comment: I added a roll-your-own approach that should work as well. As Jonathan noted in his answer, though, doing so requires you to think about some special cases that standard lib modules are likely to automatically account for.

Answer (score 0):

The Best and Most customizable way to do it is like this:

```
import numpy as np  # import package for scientific computing

dna1 = str(np.load('dna1.npy'))
repeat = 'TTTT'

def get_num_of_repeats(dna, repeat):
    repeats = 0
    for i in range(len(dna) - len(repeat) + 1):
        if dna[i:i+len(repeat)] == repeat:
            repeats += 1
    return repeats

repeats = get_num_of_repeats(dna1, repeat)
print ('{repeat} occurs {n} times in dna1'.format(repeat=repeat, n=repeats))
```

I simply created a function `get_num_of_repeats` that requests the dna variable and the pattern to watch for and returns the number of repeats.  Depending on how you want the algorithm to function, things might get difficult when you are looking for a pattern such as `'TTTT'` and a part of the dna has `'TTTTT'`.  I can give you follow up assistance to define the desired behavior.